# Java Dialog - Find out if OK is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, joptionpane

I have a dialog for a client-GUI that asks for the IP and Port of the server one wants to connect to. I have everything else, but how would I make it so that when the user clicks "OK" on my dialog box, that it runs something? Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ClientDialog {
    JTextField ip = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField port = new JTextField(20);
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    Client client = new Client();
    JOptionPane optionPane;

    public void CreateDialog(){

        Object msg[] = {"IP: ", ip, "\nPort: ", port};

        optionPane = new JOptionPane();
        optionPane.setMessage(msg);
        optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "Connect to a server");
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        if(dialog == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
            System.out.println(ip);

            String ipMsg = ip.getText();
            int portMsg = Integer.parseInt(port.getText());

            gui.CreateConsole(client, ipMsg, portMsg);
        }

    }

}   //End class
```

I know that the code isn't correct, but what I want is that when the user hits "OK" on the dialog, I can run some code. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a JDialog from a JOptionPane object rather than more simply just showing the JOptionPane? You want a modal dialog, I imagine, and so a JOptionPane should work fine by itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `showConfirmDialog` instead

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(myParent, "Narrative", 
       "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

and there you can test for various returns value from `JDialog/JOptionPane`

```
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 
              JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION, 
              JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION, etc..
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest creating a `JPanel` and using `JOptionpane.showConfirmDialog()` (or even `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` to display the dialog and retrieve the option. Here's a modification of your code as an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ClientDialog {
    private JTextField ip = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField port = new JTextField(20);
    private JOptionPane optionPane;
    private JPanel panel;

    public void CreateDialog(){

        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        panel.add(new JLabel("IP"));
        panel.add(ip);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Port"));
        panel.add(port);

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Client Dialog", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("OK!"); // do something
        }
    }

}

public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      ClientDialog c = new ClientDialog();
      c.CreateDialog();
   }

}
```

Damn, took too long to post. Anyway just design the layout of the `JPanel` as you would for any other sort of frame.

Answer (score 5):

Please understand that the 2nd parameter in a JOptionPane, the object parameter, can be any Swing component including a JPanel that holds a simple or complex GUI.

Consider creating a JPanel, placing a few components in it including JLabels and two JTextFields, one for IP, one for port, and then displaying this JPanel in a JOptionPane. Then you can easily check if OK has been pressed and act accordingly.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class OptionEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField ipField = new JTextField(10);
      final JTextField portField = new JTextField(10);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JLabel("IP:"));
      panel.add(ipField);

      panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      panel.add(new JLabel("Port:"));
      panel.add(portField);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,
            "Enter Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("IP: " + ipField.getText());
         System.out.println("Port: " + portField.getText());
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solutions.
If you want not to use something else, this is a working example:
1) set DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE to ensure user MUST press OK
2) verify if the JDialog is still visible.

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setModal(false);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
while(dialog.isVisible())try{Thread.sleep(50);}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
```

This can be a solution if you want to implement a non-modal dialog box.