# Handling of JOptionPane cancel button, which takes string as input

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to take input as string from user through a Input dialog box, and also handle the situation if user presses cancel button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object) . `null` is returned if the user chooses "Cancel" .

Comment: @Berger How about upgrading that comment to an answer?

Comment: Why even SO community try to answer questions like that. Those type of question asked millions of times and still getting answers.. Just google your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object)) method of class `JOptionPane` .

If the user hits *Cancel*, the returned value is `null`.

Also note, as @mKorbel said in the comments, that you will also get `null` if the windows has been closed directly.

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter something");

if(result == null){


    System.out.println("User pressed CANCEL, or window has been closed");
}
else{

    // do something with the String
}
```

Comment: disagree, because `result != null`, `JOptionPane` has all `windows events` implemented in API (closing, event from escape key, .....)

Comment: @mKorbel : That's right, but  will you agree that getting `null` at least means that the `Ok` button wasn't chosen ?

Comment: [there is something that I ....e.g. :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582851/714968)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(result == null){
    System.out.println("User pressed CANCEL, or window has been closed");
    System.exit(0);
}
```