# how to run JOptionPane object

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have this code to run a JOptionPane object

```
import import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TheComboBoxes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
            "The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
            + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
            + "Do you understand?",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    optionPane.createDialog("click");
}
}
```

however when i run the createDialog method nothing happens, how to i run the JOptionPane object properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582743/java-dialog-find-out-if-ok-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TheComboBoxes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
                + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n" + "Do you understand?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("click");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Use the JDialog to show your window